# Conditional formatting MS Access continuous form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a continuous form on MS Access 2019. The data source of the form is a query. It has date field as column from the query and unbounded text box. I also have day, month and year values present on the same form from three other unbounded controls.

I am trying to put conditional formatting expression for the unbounded textbox in MS Access but it is not changing the background color. My computer setting shows date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

I tried for the following but without success:

```vb
"[Data]=#" & [Me!txtdate.Value] & "-" & [Me!txtCurrMonth.value] & "-" & [Me!cboYear.value] & "#"
```

```vb
[Data]= "#" & [txtdate] & "-" & [txtCurrMonth] & "-" & [cboYear] & "#"
```

Please help with the correct expression for conditional formatting when date has to be formed by picking values from three other controls on the same form.

Thanks

Comment: Just for additional information Data is the name of the field coming from query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the [`DateSerial`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/dateserial-function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503) function to return a date value from the three unbound controls.

Since this function returns a date value directly rather than a string representation of a date, it avoids potential regional differences in date format.

For example, try setting the Conditional Formatting expression to the folllowing:

```
DateValue([Date]) = DateSerial([cboYear],[txtCurrMonth],[txtdate])
```

Here I've also used the [`DateValue`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/datevalue-function-03878f08-b0db-42df-8a0c-279939637c6f) function to return only the date component from a datetime value which could have both a date & time component.

Comment: Thanks Lee. I tried but it is not working. Is there a way to hard code and check if the above works. e.g. I have a record with Data as 01-12-2019, so can I check with hard coded value inside DateSerial and I will then incrementally change them to use variables.

Comment: Is `Data` a true date value, or is it merely a string which looks like a date?

Comment: Yes, its data type is Date/Time

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for the possibility of your `Data` values also having a time component.

Comment: You could also test the value returned by `DateSerial` by adding another textbox to your form with **Control Source** set to `=DateSerial([cboYear],[txtCurrMonth],[txtdate])`